# Multiple SVG <object> in one page

Tags: html, dom, svg

If an SVG image is embedded using an `<object>` element in an HTML document, does the SVG content have a separate DOM? (Separated from the DOM of the page itself.)

Specifically, if I embed several SVG images and they contain `id` tags that are unique within the image, but not unique across images, will that be OK?

Comment: @ZachSaucier <object> is more or less the same as an <iframe>, whatever you referece will be parsed into a separate document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be OK. All id's in the object are hidden.

SVG within an object can include both local requests, plus function calls that are resident in the parent HTML.  These functions can perform actions in either the parent html document and/or within the object.
**The parent, however, cannot directly access the object's svg elements.**

Below is an example that shows various parent vs local object functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>SVG in Object : local requests &amp; parent.functions</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
<h4>SVG in Object : local requests &amp; parent.functions </h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
SVG within an object can include both local requests, plus function calls that are resident in the parent HTML.  These functions can perform actions in either the parent html document and/or within the object.
<i>The parent, however, cannot directly access the object's svg elements.</i>
</div>
<table>
<tr align=center>
<td>
<div style='width:400px;height:400px;background-color:lightgreen'>
<object data="obj.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="objsvg" width="400" height="400"></object><br />
</div>
<i>object SVG</i>
</td>
<td>
<div id=svgDiv style='width:400px;height:400px;background-color:lightgreen'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400" id="mySVG">
<circle id="myCircle" cx="200" cy="50" fill="red" r="40" />
<rect id="myRect" x="160" y="200" fill="green" width="150" height="120" />
</svg>
</div>
<i>inline SVG (parent)</i>
</td>
</tr></table>
<br />
<i>Click on elements in the object</i><br /><br />
&lt;object data="obj.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="objsvg"  width="400" height="400"&gt;&lt;/object&gt;
<br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>
<div id='browserDiv' style='padding:5px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;background-color:gainsboro;'>OK in:IE11/CH32/FF23<br /></div>
<script id=myScript>
/*  obj.svg file
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" id="mySVG">
<circle onclick="myRect.setAttribute('fill','white')"  id="myCircle" cx="100" cy="100" fill="blue" r="80" />
<rect onclick="parent.clickMe(evt)" id="myRect" x="160" y="200" fill="red" width="200" height="100" />
<ellipse onclick='parent.myCircle.setAttribute("fill","plum")' cx='180' cy='100' rx='80' ry='40' fill='lime' />
</svg>
*/

/* ---only works in IE---
 onclick="myRect.setAttribute('fill','white')"
*/

//---function call in object---
function clickMe(evt)
{
   var target=evt.target
   target.setAttribute("fill","orange")
   parent.myRect.setAttribute("fill","orange")
}
</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    jsValue.value=myScript.text

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```